# Removing directories from PATH

Tags: bash, path, root

I am trying to run rkhunter, but it is giving me this output:

```
stack/security/rkhunter-1.4.6
➜ sudo rkhunter --check
Password:
Invalid BINDIR configuration option: Invalid 
directory found: ~/.dotnet/tools
Invalid BINDIR configuration option: Invalid 
directory found: 
Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

How do I go into my PATH variable and remove these directories from all shell sessions? None of these directories are in my .bash_profile or .bashrc.

Comment: There is no reference to BINDIR in rkhunter.conf. And what do you mean by root's PATH? @dsstorefile1

Comment: root's PATH is the PATH of the user root. But `sudo` without `-i` shouldn't read root's profile. Themessage is about `BINDIR`. Try `env -i /usr/bin/sudo rkhunter --check`.

Comment: stack/security/rkhunter-1.4.6
➜ env -i /usr/bin/sudo rkhunter --check
Password:
sudo: rkhunter: command not found @RalfFriedl

Comment: Do you want me to post some of the information from rkhunter.conf?@dsstorefile1

Comment: If `rkhunter` is not found, then try `env -i /usr/bin/sudo $(type -p rkhunter) --check`.

Comment: same response. rkhunter: command not found @RalfFriedl

Comment: Yes. They are all in the echo $PATH.

Comment: Add that to my .bash_profile or literally enter that into my terminal?

Comment: Awesome. That worked. This may be off topic, but do you know if it says  "warning", does that mean I have one or is it just a warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terminal, copy the results of path.

```
echo $PATH

/your/:~/path/:~/.dotnet/tools:/here/:
```

Paste the contents of PATH into a text editor and remove the troublesome directory in the PATH from between PATH's delimiters, usually `:`.

Clear the PATH.

```
export PATH=""
```

Copy the edited PATH, and store it back in PATH.

```
export PATH="/your/:~/path/:/here/"
```